# Storing components in an Entity System

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary, entity

*Note: this introduction is about entity systems. But, even if you don't know what these are, or haven't implemented them yourself, it's pretty basic and if you have general Javascript experience you will probably qualify more than enough to answer.*

I am reading [articles](http://t-machine.org/index.php/2007/09/03/entity-systems-are-the-future-of-mmog-development-part-1/) about Entity Systems on the T=machine blog.

The author, Adam, suggests that an entity should just be an id, that can be used to obtain it's components (ie, the actual data that the entity is supposed to represent).

I chose the model where all entities should be stored in "one place", and my primary suspects for implementing this storage are the array-of-arrays approach many people use, which would imply **dynamic** entity id's that represent the *index* of a component belonging to an entity, while components are grouped by type in that "one place" (from now on I'll just call it "storage"), which I plan to implement as a `Scene`. The `Scene` would be an object that handles entity composition, storage, and can do some basic operations on entities (`.addComponent(entityID, component)` and such).

I am not concerned about the `Scene` object, I'm pretty sure that it's a good design, but what I am not sure is the implementation of the storage.

I have two options:

**A)** Go with the array-of-array approach, in which the storage looks like this:

```
//storage[i][j] - i denotes component type, while j denotes the entity, this returns a component instance
//j this is the entity id

[
    [ComponentPosition, ComponentPosition, ComponentPosition],
    [ComponentVelocity, undefined, ComponentVelocity],
    [ComponentCamera, undefined, undefined]
]

//It's obvious that the entity `1` doesn't have the velocity and camera components, for example.
```

**B)** Implement the storage object as a dictionary (technically an object in Javascript)

```
{
    "componentType": 
    {
        "entityId": ComponentInstance
    }
}
```

The dictionary approach  would imply that entity id's are **static**, which seems like a very good thing for implementing game loops and other functionality outside the Entity System itself. Also, this means that systems could easily store an array of entity ids that they are interested in. The entityId variable would also be a string, as opposed to an integer index, obviously.

The reason why I am against array-of-arrays approach is that deleting entities would make other entity ids change when a single entity is deleted.

Actual implementation details may wary, but I would like to know which approach would be better performance wise?

Things that I am also interested in (please be as cross-platform as possible, but if needed be, use V8 as an example):

- How big is the overhead when accessing properties, and how is that implemented under the hoof? Lets say that they are being access from inside the local scope.
- What is `undefined` in memory, and how much does it take? I ask this, because in the array-of-arrays approach all of the inner arrays must be of the same length, and if an entity doesn't have a certain component, that field is set to `undefined`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't worry about the Array. It is an Object in JavaScript i.e. no "real" arrays, it's just the indices are a numeric "names" for the properties of the object (dictionary, hash, map).

The idea is simple, an Array has a length property that allows for loops to know where to stop iterating. By simply removing an element off the Array (remember, it's an Object) the length property doesn't actually change. So...

```
// create an array object
var array = ['one','two', 'three'];
console.log(array.length); // 3
// these don't actually change the length
delete array['two']; // 'remove' the property with key 'two'
console.log(array.length); // 3
array['two'] = undefined; // put undefined as the value to the property with key 'two'
console.log(array.length); // 3
array.splice(1,1); // remove the second element, and reorder
console.log(array.length); // 2
console.log(array); // ['one','three']
```

1. You've got to realize that JavaScript doesn't "work" like you expect. Performance wise objects and arrays are same i.e. arrays are accessed like dictionaries;
2. Scope is not like other "c style" languages. There are **only global and function scopes** i.e. no block scope (never write for(var i) inside another for(var i));
3. undefined in memory takes exactly the same amount as null . The difference is that null is deliberate missing of value, while undefined is just accidental (non-deliberate) missing;
4. Don't check if a field exists by doing `if(array['two'])` because, a field can actually hold the falsy values of **undefined, null, 0, "", false** and evaluate as false. Always check with `if('two' in array)`;
5. When looping with `for(key in array)` always use `if(array.hasOwnProperty(key))` so you don't iterate over a prototype's property (the parent's in a manner of speaking). Also, objects created by a constructor function might loop with the 'constructor' key also.

Comment: Aha, so, basically, this means that I can have an array with 999999999999 elements, with the first 999999999998 ones being `undefined` and the last one being `1`, and it would take the same amount of memory as `[1]`?

Comment: Exactly. Although, since you have no benefit of faster execution (you deal with dictionaries, not arrays) you might as well use the objects and put meaningful names for properties.
If you have more ambiguities, please add them to question, otherwise, just accept my answer :)

Comment: This answer seems to have a lot of misconceptions. For instance, there is no "property with key 'two'" in the variable array; there is an element with the value 'two'. It is additionally incorrect for most modern JavaScript engines to state that the performance is identical; while accessing arrays and objects has a similar syntax, the internal implementation thereof is vastly different. Arrays will be orders of magnitudes faster for certain operations; see http://news.qooxdoo.org/javascript-array-performance-oddities-characteristics

Comment: Your missconception: 
>>For instance, there is no "property with key 'two'" in the variable array; there is an element with the value 'two'.<<

Now if you ran the code, you'd see that there **IS A PROPERTY AND NOT AN ELEMENT BECAUSE THE LENGTH DOESN'T CHANGE** when you add the property, but does when you add the element i.e. `length` is magical and changes when there are "numerical" keys assigned. NB: the numbers used for access (ex: array[2]) also get converted to strings internally ( `console.log(array[1], array['1'])` ). Next time don't downvote before you clear your own misconceptions.